# An audio file recorded using MediaRecorder in Android not playing properly on PC

Tags: android, audio, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am working on recording audio using [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html).

And I am setting required parameters as follows:

```
private void startRecording() { 

       mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
       mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
       mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);             // Mono channel - my requirement
       mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);      // 8Khz - my requirement
       mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16000);  // 16 kbps - my requirement

       mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);        
       mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
       mRecorder.setOutputFile(MY_FILE_NAME);

       mRecorder.prepare();
       mRecorder.start();
}
```

The audio is recorded fine and mp4 file is created on my SD card, and it plays fine when I play file on my android device. However when I play file on PC the voice is fast forwarded with glitches in between every 2 to 3 seconds.But if I use stereo ie. 2 channels then the song is played fine on PC as well.

When I check the properties of the recorded audio file on PC, I get following values:

> Channels    : Stereo
>
> Sample rate : 16000 Hz
>
> BitRate     : 96 kbps

I face problem when I try to play that file on Windows media player on Windows machine, Movie player on Ubuntu, even on Mac machine the file is not played properly. I am recording file on Micromax A116 with android version 4.1.2 and Samsung Galaxy Note with version 4.1.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From your question itself is clear that you recorded with Stereo type recorder and playing without stereo gives Mono effect, most mono effect are failed with pc audio players, it wont give u a perfect Sound. Install any audio Codec packs available free in many sites and then test it.

Comment: But I am setting the channel value as Mono, for recording.

Comment: See you are setting audio channels as 1(Mono) but output is stereo in PC, do check in mobile itself what properties is there and compare with PC. One more thing encoding in your recorder is AAC(AAC Low Complexity) instead of use HE_AAC(High Efficiency AAC) for best resuls in PC.

Answer (score 0):

just make that file `THREE_GPP`
and `Audioencoder` as `AMR_NB`